# Как ограничить диапазон дат в bootstrap datepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap

Использую плагин `bootstrap datepicker` для выбора дат. Как можно прописать ограничение, чтобы можно было выбрать даты в диапазоне от 18 до 100 лет?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В Datepicker есть свойства `startDate` и `endDate`, с помощью которых вы можете задать нужный диапазон дат.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        startDate: -20,
        endDate: "+1M +10D"
    });
});
```

[Информация в документации bootstrap-datepicker](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html)

Comment: Я использую не jQuery datepicker а bootstrap datepicker там такой метод не работает

Comment: Отредактировал свой пост, проверьте этот вариант.

Comment: Спасибо! Вот так правильно будет для конкретного примера startDate: "-100y",
          endDate: "-18y"